# Core Data EXC_BAD_ACCESS Randomly On Save

Tags: ios, core-data

My app receives a crash on a core data save. Following is the Stack:

```
#0  0x01646725 in _PFObjectIDFastEquals64 ()
#1  0x018aba17 in __CFDictionaryEquateKeys ()
#2  0x018f0967 in ___CFBasicHashFindBucket_Linear ()
#3  0x017fb9ab in CFBasicHashSetValue ()
#4  0x017fb799 in CFDictionarySetValue ()
#5  0x0163cab3 in _PFCMT_SetValue ()
#6  0x01668d68 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _changeIDsForManagedObjects:toIDs:] ()
#7  0x0167aaff in -[NSSQLCore commitChanges:] ()
#8  0x0166e070 in -[NSSQLCore saveChanges:] ()
#9  0x0162c199 in -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] ()
#10 0x016dc70b in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] ()
#11 0x01664948 in -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] ()
#12 0x000c8ee4 in -[SensorController performDataRecord] (self=0x69633d0, _cmd=0x27eaa4) at   SensorController.m:760
#13 0x01d7cefc in -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] ()
#14 0x01d8f506 in -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] ()
#15 0x000c8d60 in -[SensorController recordData] (self=0x69633d0, _cmd=0x27eab6) at SensorController.m:744
#16 0x01d94749 in __NSFireTimer ()
#17 0x018ba8c3 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#18 0x018bbe74 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#19 0x018182c9 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#20 0x01817840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#21 0x01817761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#22 0x027cc1c4 in GSEventRunModal ()
#23 0x027cc289 in GSEventRun ()
#24 0x007b6c93 in UIApplicationMain ()
#25 0x00083801 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff60c) at main.m:50
```

The data is inserted on a thread, using a non-main-thread context. This only occurs in infrequent occasions, but still often enough to crash frequently after long use. As you can see from the stack, I'm performing the save on the main thread, and waiting for it to complete.

Also, just as a precaution, I'm looking the context before the save.

Finally, the context is set to retain objects:
`[context setRetainsRegisteredObjects:YES];`

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Not much to go on but you should be saving on the same thread that the objects were inserted/updated on.

It looks like the crash is occurring when the store is trying to alter object ids. That in turn suggest perhaps you have two or more instantiate objects keyed to the same store representation.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the EXC_BAD_ACCESS always comes from trying to touch on a variable that has been released or dealloc'd. Try checking for memory leaks or that the area it is blowing up in has everything accounted for.